# Using HP Fortify SCA to scan Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, gcc, rhel, fortify

I'm trying to use HP Fortify SCA to scan RHEL7.5 server kernel [linux-3.10.0-862.el7]. I'm on the RHEL workstation OS which is on virtualbox.

In the working dir I'm doing:

> "sourceanalyzer -b mybuild touchless make"

The kernel compiles using "make" by itself. The sourceanalyzer goes through some of the code but it seems to error out when it comes to:

> CC arch/x86/purgatory/purgatory.o

Is Fortify capable of scanning the kernel? Do I need to use more complex commands to scan it?

The output error segment is:

> touchless-script
>   /home/sail/.fortify/sca18.1/build/myscan/build6382721854835965459/gcc
>   called with args: -Wp,-MD,arch/x86/purgatory/.purgatory.o.d -nostdinc
>   -isystem touchless-script /home/sail/.fortify/sca18.1/build/myscan/build6382721854835965459/gcc
>   called with args: -print-file-name=include
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include -I./arch/x86/include
>   -Iarch/x86/include/generated -Iinclude -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -Iinclude/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -c -MD -Os -mcmodel=large -m64 -DKBUILD_STR(s)=#s -DKBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(purgatory) -DKBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(purgatory) -c -o arch/x86/purgatory/.tmp_purgatory.o arch/x86/purgatory/purgatory.c
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include [warning]: File called
>   not found [warning]: File with not found [warning]: File args: not
>   found [warning]: File /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include
>   not found gcc: error: called: No such file or directory gcc: error:
>   with: No such file or directory gcc: error: args:: No such file or
>   directory objdump: 'arch/x86/purgatory/.tmp_purgatory.o': No such file
>   mv: cannot stat ‘arch/x86/purgatory/.tmp_purgatory.o’: No such file or
>   directory 
>   make[1]: *** [arch/x86/purgatory/purgatory.o] Error 1 make:
>   *** [archprepare] Error 2

Comment: Does the kernel build in your environment without using `sourceanalyzer.exe`?

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm confused as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that when Fortify (or any other static analyzer) fails to get along with your build system, you should integrate it into the compiler. That is, tell the Makefile to use your shell script for the compiler:

```
make GCC=gcc_and_fortify.sh
```

The gcc_and_fortify.sh script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARGS=$@
# run GCC
gcc $ARGS
# run Fortify
sourceanalyzer -b my_project $ARGS
```